# Windows 8 upgrade from Store

Tags: windows-8, windows-store, windows-8.1-upgrade

According to Microsoft - the Windows 8 Store was closed on 01.06.2019 and no APP UPDATES could be installed after this date.

Does this mean that the Windows 8.1 upgrade was deleted from the store at the same time?

I had to re-install my OEM Windows 8 PC and consequently updated it to 8.1 on March 2020 using Microsoft Store. How could it be possible? Should I now be concerned or was the upgrade (8 to 8.1) available for some time in the store after it "closed"?

Comment: Is there any reason you haven't upgraded to Win10 yet? I mean you're on the OS that 80% of the world hated anyway, most of which has been improved in Win10.

Comment: On the flip side @Tetsujin , windows 8 is what the xbox runs under the hood 8^P .. and I too am in the 80% that hated it.

Answer (score 0):

(Heads up: the "Windows 8 Store" and the "Microsoft Store" are not the same thing!)

According to [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2018/08/20/important-dates-regarding-apps-with-windows-phone-8-x-and-earlier-and-windows-8-8-1-packages-submitted-to-microsoft-store/#CdtbKiuJ5fPvCToK.97) on the Windows blog, Microsoft ceased app updates for Windows 8 **Phone** on the first of July, 2019:

> July 1st, 2019 – Microsoft will stop distributing app updates to Windows Phone 8.x or earlier devices.
>
> - You’ll still be able to publish updates to all apps (including those with Windows Phone 8.x or earlier packages). However, these updates will only be made available to Windows 10 devices.

Windows 8 & 8.1 continue to receive app updates up until the first of July, **2023**:

> July 1st, 2023 – Microsoft will stop distributing app updates to Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 devices.
>
> - You’ll still be able to publish updates to all apps (including those with Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 packages). However, these updates
>   will only be made available to Windows 10 devices.

To sum it up: While the Windows 8 store is technically "closed" for new apps, existing apps can still be updated up until 2023.

Having that said there's no need to be concerned about being able to upgrade to 8.1. While the Windows 8 store has closed, the upgrade is also available from Microsoft's own website according to its [upgrade guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/update-to-windows-8-1-from-windows-8-17fc54a7-a465-6b5a-c1a0-34140afd0669):

> The Store is no longer open for Windows 8, so you'll need to download Windows 8.1 as a free update.
>
> 1. Go to the [Windows 8.1 download page](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows8ISO) and select your Windows edition.
> 2. Select Confirm and follow the remaining prompts to begin the download.
> 3. The update will download and install in the background while you use your PC to do other things. The installer will check to make sure
>    you have enough disk space, that your apps and devices will work with
>    Windows 8.1 or Windows RT 8.1, and that you have all the required
>    updates.
>
> In some cases, the installer might find something you need to take care of before you can continue installing the update. If so, you'll
> see a message telling you what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The micrisoft guide you referred says: "The Store is no longer open for Windows 8, so you'll need to download Windows 8.1 as a free update.

    Go to the Windows 8.1 download page and select your Windows edition."   That means they provide a solution through download website.  But it worked in my case through the Windows 8 Store on March 2020, when the store supposed to be closed.  Is the store being abandoned by micrisoft and somebody has taken over/hacked it? Or was it still possible to get the upgrade from store for a certain period after the store was closed?

Comment: @Verinika _existing_ items on the store were and are still available so it is very possible that the upgrade could still be downloaded that way back then if not today. You shouldn't be concerned about the store getting hacked - You would've read about it in the news if someone managed to do that.